# Cant initialize Field on Custom DataSink (Flink CEP)

Tags: java-8, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

I have a problem  with the Apache Flink Streaming API.

I could manage to set up the whole CEP-Environment with a custom DataSource and when using a standard sink on that source like "print()", everything works fine.

This is what my sink looks like now:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class EventDataConsumer extends RichSinkFunction<EventData>{

private final transient Consumer<EventData> consumer;

    @Override
    public void invoke(EventData eventData) throws Exception {
        consumer.accept(eventData);
    }
}
```

What I try to achieve ist, to pass a method reference to this SinkFunction, which shall be executed for each element in my DataStream.

This is how I initialize the SinkFunction:

```
EventDataConsumer consumer = new EventDataConsumer(someService::handleEventData);
outStream.addSink(consumer);
```

My Problem is, that when I set a breakpoint in the "invoke" method of my custom sink, the consumer appears to be null even though I call the constructor explicitly, which assigns the consumer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Sink is distributed to as many instances as the parallelism of the sink it should be serializable. When executing on cluster the `Sink` is serialised sent to `TaskManagers` where it is deserialised.

In your example the `consumer` field is `transient`, that is why after serialisation it becomes `null`.

Comment: Thanks, that really helps understanding the problem. Any idea on how to make a method reference serializable?

Comment: I meant the Consumer-Field, sorry. I tried creating an SerializableConsumer-Interface which extends the Consumer and Serializable-Interface but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Hmm it should work this way. Are you sure you removed the `transient` keyword? Also make sure the method is really serializable. Remember that lambdas usually have some closure that also needs to be serializable. In your example `someService` also needs to be serializable.